# Existence of a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it correct that if the bracket of two vectors $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ equals zero, then  a submanifold tangent to $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ exists?

Answer (score 3):

More formally, this is Frobenius' theorem : [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29) if you have a subbundle, then the subbundle is integrable , i.e., there exists a submanifold whose tangent space coincides with the subbundle, if the Lie bracket of two vectors in the subbundle also takes values in the subbundle. So you want closure of vector fields under taking the Lie bracket.

An interesting case to look at is that of contact manifolds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry , EDIT , in the case of 3-manifolds, contact manifolds are precisely those where the integrability condition is not satisfied at any point.  The contact distribution is then given as the kernel of a 1-form $\omega$ satisfying $ \omega \wedge d\omega \neq 0$ so that, if $\omega$ is given globally, then the manifold is orientable (because $\omega \wedge d\omega$ is an orientation form; notice that the contact forms may be defined locally in such a way that they cannot be coherently patched-up into a globally-defined form).
As pointed out by Jack Lee in the comments, the situation becomes more complicated in higher dimensions, a distribution may be nowhere-integrable and still may not be a contact bundle. The conditions for a higher-dimensional distribution $D$ to be a contact distribution (as pointed out by Jack Lee) is then that the map $(X,Y) \rightarrow [X,Y] mod D$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form.

Comment: That characterization of contact manifolds is not quite accurate. In 3 dimensions, a contact structure is a 2D distribution that doesn't satisfy the integrability condition (closure under Lie brackets) at any point, not just one that doesn't satisfy it on any open set. But in higher dimensions, it's possible for a distribution to be nonintegrable everywhere and yet not be a contact bundle. The contact condition for a distribution $H$ is that the map $(X,Y) \mapsto [X,Y] \mod H$ is a nondegenerate bilinear form, while nonintegrability just says it's nonzero.

Comment: @Jack Lee: Thanks, yes, I was thinking of 3-manifolds (and still wrong then.) Please see my edit.

Comment: One minor remark: There are several notions of a submanifold, the one you are using is of an injective immersion $M\to N$, which, typically, is not an embedding (since it might not be proper).

Comment: @studious: Thanks for the comment.